# How is this code getting executed in python ? What is the sequence of execution with multiple for loops here?

Tags: python, list, numpy

```
a = np.array(
    [
        [
            [
                get_score(weights[i][k], vec, y)
                for vec in get_vector()
            ]
            for k in range(x)
        ]
        for i in range(y)
    ]
)
```

How is the execution sequence in this code ?

Comment: Running your code I get following sequence of execution (assuming `numpy` was imported): A NameError in line 4, then the execution stops.

Answer (score 3):

It is eqivalent to this:

```
a = []
for i in range(y):
    for k in range(x):
        for vec in get_vector():
            a.append(get_score(weights[i][k], vec, y))
a = np.array(a)
```

Comment: does the sequence of for loops matter or they could be run in any sequence ?

Comment: @honolulu Well try different sequences, and you'll see it matters. You'll also see that this is obviously *not* equivalent (builds a 1D structure instead of a 3D structure) and that it's a mystery how this got two upvotes.